# What are these Black-Backgrounded numbers on the "Form" when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I get the following when debugging a C# Windows Store application in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10:

[image]

What are these numbers? There are no numbers in the code at all. It's supposed to be the image that's behind it only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These numbers are extra debuging information related to the [EnableFrameRateCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh701818(v=win.10).aspx).

If you take a look at your App.xaml.cs code, you'll see that the FrameRateCounter has been initialized programmatically for debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
   this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
}
#endif
```